# How is system of rewards is working in reinforcement learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

As far as I've got the whole system of rewards depends on the loss function in the neural network to learn. Let's suppose that loss function is -R(rewards) for simplification. If the reward is positive than the loss is negative, so we are loosening the model. If rewards are negative than we are working on strengthening the model. Is this statement correct?
And, finally, does bigger values of output layer lead to a better model?
Is inflation in output neurons is necessary to increase the complexity and accuracy of the model?
Or plus and minus R in loss function is enough to properly train the model for RL?

Comment: could you post some [input data, code and expected output](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without it it is quite diffiuclt to help. Moreover your question more of fundamental kind and it is better to ask it at stat, machine learning or computer science forums of SE.